# Access ro.serialno from native in Android 8?

Tags: android, c, permissions, native

I need some help. I have an app that is mostly written in native C code. I use the `__system_property_get(const char * name, char * value)` method to read the serial nr. of the device at various points in my native code. With Android 8 I always get a "Access denied" message now.
**libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"**
Is there a way for me to still be able to read the serial nr. in Android 8? I tried switching to targetSDKversion < 26 but it still gives me a "Access denied" message. I do get the correct values if I use Java with `Build.SERIAL` (regardless of SDK version) and `Build.getSerial()` in SDK version 26 if I grant the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. But I cannot read these values in Java and pass them to the native code without a huge rewrite of the native code.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

I met this problem too. Finally I find the root cause of the problem. In Android O, SELinux sets a lot of limitations in system property. In this case, There is a **neverallow** to limit read serial number except some domain in whitelist.

For more specific information, you can read code in `system/sepolicy/public/domain.te`:

```
neverallow {
  domain
  -adbd
  -dumpstate
  -hal_drm
  -init
  -mediadrmserver
  -recovery
  -shell
  -system_server
} serialno_prop:file r_file_perms;
```

Comment: Where do you paste this??

Answer (score 1):

If you have the hand on AOSP:

1. Put `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` to `AdnroidMainfest`
2. Run app like `system_app`.
3. Change in `Android.mk`. `LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/app`.

Or you can duplicate the property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not call it on the UI thread, so this error occur.

If you call it on non-ui thread, you should create opengl context at first.